# Insert multiple rows based on what a cell contains, and then filling them

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I have the following situation

```
1  Type 1         Data 1    Data 2   Data 3   Data 4
2  Type 1         Data 5    Data 6   Data 7   Data 8
3  Type 2         Data 9    Data 10  Data 11  Data 12
etc.
```

Where the first column is a column of index and the 3rd column is empty. (There are 5 more empty columns between column 3 and column where data starts. Data actually starts at column 9, but for displaying purposes I wrote it like that).

What I want to do is, based on cells of column B, if it is Type 1, add 5 empty rows below, and if it is Type 2, add 8 empty rows below. In other words, Type 1 rows have 5 "sons" rows, and Type 2 rows have 8 "sons" rows

Now I need to fill these rows. I have a second sheet with a list of 5 items for Type 1 and 8 items for type 2:

```
item 1.1         item 2.1
item 1.2         item 2.2
item 1.3         item 2.3
item 1.4         item 2.4
item 1.5         item 2.5
                 item 2.6
                 item 2.7
                 item 2.8
```

I need it to look like this (empty rows in the following are only for display purposes on this page, there has not to be any empty row in the actual sheet):

```
1  Type 1            Data 1    Data 2    Data 3   Data 4
2  Item 1.1    1               Data 2             Data 4
3  Item 1.2    1               Data 2             Data 4 
4  Item 1.3    1               Data 2             Data 4
5  Item 1.4    1               Data 2             Data 4 
6  Item 1.5    1               Data 2             Data 4

7  Type 1            Data 5    Data 6    Data 7   Data 8
8  Item 1.1    7               Data 6             Data 8
10 Item 1.2    7               Data 6             Data 8
11 Item 1.3    7               Data 6             Data 8
12 Item 1.4    7               Data 6             Data 8
13 Item 1.5    7               Data 6             Data 8

14 Type 2            Data 9    Data 10   Data 11  Data 12
15 item 2.1    14              Data 10            Data 12
16 item 2.2    14              Data 10            Data 12
17 item 2.3    14              Data 10            Data 12
18 item 2.4    14              Data 10            Data 12
19 item 2.5    14              Data 10            Data 12
20 item 2.6    14              Data 10            Data 12
21 item 2.7    14              Data 10            Data 12
22 item 2.8    14              Data 10            Data 12
etc.
```

Note that there has been a reindexation, and 3rd column has now been filled with the "parent" index (except for the parent ones, which will remain empty as shown).

About the distribution of column B, usually I have all the Type 1 altogether, and then the type 2. (As the setup of this post).

I have been doing macros for a couple of months, but I cannot come up with a macro for this since the reindex and the resize are really puzzling me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You missed to ask a question, and this is no free code writing service. Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question to improve it and show the code you already have tried and which errors you get.

Comment: I suspect that you are getting confused between `columns` and `rows`. When you say `3rd row`, I'm presuming you mean `3rd column`?. Don't think it should be too difficult to achieve but please provide what you have tried so far.. this could be code or formula's

Answer (score 0):

Assume the following worksheets:

**Worksheet "DataTable"**
[image]

**Worksheet "Items"**
*Note that the header in row 1 here must match the DataTable column B data!*
[image]

**With this code …**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FillInItems()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet 'define data sheet
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataTable")

    Dim wsItems As Worksheet 'define items sheet
    Set wsItems = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Items")

    Dim LastRow As Long 'find last used row in data
    LastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = 1 'data starts in row 1 (no headers)

    Dim idx As Long 'index counter in column A
    idx = wsData.Cells(1, "A").Value 'get index counter

    Do While iRow <= LastRow 'loop through all data rows
        Dim itmCol As Variant
        itmCol = Application.Match(wsData.Cells(iRow, "B").Value, wsItems.Rows(1), 0) 'find type
        If Not IsError(itmCol) Then
            Dim itmCount As Long
            itmCount = wsItems.Cells(wsItems.Rows.Count, itmCol).End(xlUp).Row - 1

            With wsData
                'insert rows
                .Rows(iRow + 1).Resize(RowSize:=itmCount).Insert xlShiftDown

                'write index
                .Cells(iRow, "A").Value = idx
                .Cells(iRow, "A").AutoFill Destination:=.Cells(iRow, "A").Resize(RowSize:=itmCount + 1), Type:=xlFillSeries
                .Cells(iRow + 1, "C").Resize(RowSize:=itmCount).Value = idx
                idx = idx + itmCount + 1

                'write items
                .Cells(iRow + 1, "B").Resize(RowSize:=itmCount).Value = wsItems.Cells(2, itmCol).Resize(RowSize:=itmCount).Value

                'copy 2 data rows down
                .Cells(iRow, "J").AutoFill Destination:=.Cells(iRow, "J").Resize(RowSize:=itmCount + 1), Type:=xlFillCopy
                .Cells(iRow, "L").AutoFill Destination:=.Cells(iRow, "L").Resize(RowSize:=itmCount + 1), Type:=xlFillCopy
            End With

            'adjust counters (because we added rows)
            iRow = iRow + itmCount
            LastRow = LastRow + itmCount
        End If
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

**… the result will be**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    Sub test3()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LastRow1 As Long, No As Long, LastRow2 As Long, Times As Long
    Dim sType As String, Data As String, Data1 As String, Data2 As String, Data3 As String
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

        LastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Number = 1

        For i = 2 To LastRow1

            No = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value
            sType = ws1.Range("B" & i).Value
            Data = ws1.Range("C" & i).Value
            Data1 = ws1.Range("D" & i).Value
            Data2 = ws1.Range("E" & i).Value
            Data3 = ws1.Range("F" & i).Value

            If i = 2 Then
                LastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Else
                LastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            End If

            ws2.Range("A" & LastRow2 + 1).Value = Number
            ws2.Range("B" & LastRow2 + 1).Value = sType
            ws2.Range("D" & LastRow2 + 1).Value = Data
            ws2.Range("E" & LastRow2 + 1).Value = Data1
            ws2.Range("F" & LastRow2 + 1).Value = Data2
            ws2.Range("G" & LastRow2 + 1).Value = Data3

            If Right(sType, 1) = 1 Then
                Times = 5
            ElseIf Right(sType, 1) = 2 Then
                Times = 8
            End If

            For j = 1 To Times

                LastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                ws2.Range("A" & LastRow2 + 1).Value = Number + j
                ws2.Range("B" & LastRow2 + 1).Value = "Item " & Right(sType, 1) & "." & j
                ws2.Range("C" & LastRow2 + 1).Value = Number
                ws2.Range("E" & LastRow2 + 1).Value = Data1
                ws2.Range("G" & LastRow2 + 1).Value = Data3

            Next j

            Number = Number + 6

        Next i

End Sub
```